# about android subject

Tags: android-emulator

we have to create different avd for different projects in eclipse.
yes/no.I am really beginner i want to know that we can use one android virtual device for different application or not.I mean If it is a good practice to have different avd for different apps or not.

Comment: Hello sir. My answer is "yes". Now we have to find out what's the question.

Comment: No, definitely not. Was there a question somewhere?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not necessarily.

You usually create AVD for different configs (i.e. different Android versions and/or different screen parameters eg. density 160/240). You can run different projects in same AVD.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to create a different AVD for each project. @GSree is correct. The same AVD can be used for multiple projects.